# manipulate two fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i  have two fragment, fragment1 under fragment2 and fragment 1 is smaller than fragment 2.

first i make fragment 2 visible, than when i make fragment 1 visible, i want to disable all button and list in fragment 2, so user can only control fragment 1. how can i do this?

Here are my xml:

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" >
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:layout_width="200dip"
                android:layout_height="200dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it easier to use one FrameLayout as a container and then in code replace fragments if necessary?

For example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And then in activity containing the layout above:

```
if (showFragment1()) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
        add(R.id.fragmentContainer, Fragment1.newInstance());
} else {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
        add(R.id.fragmentContainer, Fragment2.newInstance());
}
```

Then you can use onActivityCreated callback in fragment classes to initializa your UI.